# in XML parser.feed(text) xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

Tags: python, xml, parsing, web-scraping

this code i tested it in ping ai and worked but didnt work in my Vstudio

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl
api_key = False
if api_key is False:
    api_key = 42
    service_url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/xml?'
else:
    service_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?'
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

address = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
parm = dict()
parm['address'] = address
if api_key is not False:
    parm['key'] = api_key
url = service_url+urllib.parse.urlencode(parm)
print('retrieve ', url)

uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()

print('retrieved ', len(uh), 'characters')
datas = uh.decode()
tree = ET.fromstring(datas)
suum = 0
count = 0
counts = tree.findall('.//count')
for i in counts:
    suum +=int(i.text)
    count +=1
print(suum)
print(count)
```

my output should be.

```
Retrieving http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml
Retrieved 4189 characters
Count: 50
Sum: 2...
```

but my output is.

```
retrieve http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/xml?address=http%3A%2F%2Fpy4e-data.dr-chuck.net%2Fcomments_42.xml&key=42
retrieved  36 characters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\ياسر\python_file\project_etree.py", line 28, in <module>
    tree = ET.fromstring(datas)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\beaut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1338, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

And I don't know why I got `retrieved 36 characters`.
and should use parsing by xml because its a quiz and try to learn why didnt work with me where is the issue.

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/76843884/407651

Comment: its same and still didnt find what i should to do @mzjn –  i tried to fix url ( like u said ) but didnt work

Comment: Please do not post nearly same question with almost exact coding attempt. This post should be closed as a duplicate of previous post.

Comment: A well formed XML file has only one element at the root.  Error indicates you have an array at the root.  Most XML libraries do not accept files that are not well formed.  I can parse but need to see the XML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ParseError: not well-formed XML (from URL opened with urllib.request.urlopen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843884/parseerror-not-well-formed-xml-from-url-opened-with-urllib-request-urlopen)

Comment: here is the xml https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml @jdweng

Comment: ET.fromstring() takes a byte string of xml, but your datas is { "address": "fail", "answer" : 42 }. This is not a xml.

Comment: Duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas will show the dataframe:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url=r"https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml"
request = requests.get(url)
print(f"Retrieving: {url}")
print(f"Retrieved {len(request.text)} characters")

df = pd.read_xml(request.text, xpath='//comment')
#print(df)
print("Count:", df.shape[0])

sums = df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum().rename('total')
print("Sum:", sums)
```

Output:

```
Retrieving: https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml
Retrieved 4189 characters
Count: 50
Sum: count    2553
Name: total, dtype: int64
```

For xml.etree.ElementTree use a Session:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

s = requests.Session()

url=r"https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml"

r = s.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
print(type(r.text))

tree = ET.fromstring(r.text)
print(tree)
for elem in tree.iter():
    # do your things
    print(elem.tag)
```

Or if you need urllib, it works too:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url="https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml"

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    xml = f.read()
    # xml is a byte string
    # print(xml)

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for elem in root.iter():
    # do what you like with the xml content
    print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) which uses `lxml` underneath:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "xml")

comments = soup.select("comment")

count, s = 0, 0
for c in soup.select("comment"):
    count += 1
    s += sum(int(c.text) for c in c.select("count"))

print(count)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
50
2553
```

Comment: i should use  parsing by xml because it is a quiz

Answer (score -1):

You can use Powershell

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$uri = 'https://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($uri)

$comments = $doc.Descendants('comment')

$groups = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::GroupBy($comments,  [Func[object,object]]{ param($x) $x[0].Element('name').Value}, [Func[object,object]]{ param($y) $y[0].Element('count').Value})

$dict = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::ToDictionary($groups, [Func[object,object]]{ param($x) $x.Key}, [Func[object,object]]{ param($y) $y})

$dict
```

Results

```
Key         Value
---         -----
Romina      97
Laurie      97
Bayli       90
Siyona      90
Taisha      88
Alanda      87
Ameelia     87
Prasheeta   80
Asif        79
Risa        79
Zi          78
Danyil      76
Ediomi      76
Barry       72
Lance       72
Hattie      66
Mathu       66
Bowie       65
Samara      65
Uchenna     64
Shauni      61
Georgia     61
Rivan       59
Kenan       58
Hassan      57
Isma        57
Samanthalee 54
Alexa       51
Caine       49
Grady       47
Anne        40
Rihan       38
Alexei      37
Indie       36
Rhuairidh   36
Annoushka   32
Kenzi       25
Shahd       24
Irvine      22
Carys       21
Skye        19
Atiya       18
Rohan       18
Nuala       14
Maram       12
Carlo       12
Japleen     9
Breeanna    7
Zaaine      3
Inika       2
```